# How can I save my ui component form to the database?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form

I created a ui component, but I have no idea how to save it in the database. I know I have to pass it to the controller for it to pass to the model but I don't know how my controller should be, here's my code:

form ui component:

```
 <dataSource name="novo_desconto_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Desconto\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">novo_desconto_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="employee_details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Details</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="employee_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Nome</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="employee_salary">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Valor</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_salary</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="employee_address">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Desconto</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_address</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

DataProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Desconto\Model;
 
use Vendor\Desconto\Model\ResourceModel\Employee\CollectionFactory;
 
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $employeeCollectionFactory
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $employeeCollectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $employeeCollectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }
 
    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

My saveButton.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Desconto\Block\Adminhtml\Edit;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class SaveButton
 * @package Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit
 */
class SaveButton extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $customerAccountManagement;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry);
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $customerId = $this->getCustomerId();
        $canModify = !$customerId || !$this->customerAccountManagement->isReadonly($this->getCustomerId());
        $data = [];
        if ($canModify) {
            $data = [
                'label' => __('Salvar'),
                'class' => 'save primary',
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'save']],
                    'form-role' => 'save',
                ],
                'sort_order' => 90,
            ];
        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function getSaveUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/save', []);
    }
}




   <?php
namespace vendor\Desconto\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
class Employee extends AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\test\Model\ResourceModel\Employee');
    }
}
```

Employee/Employee.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Desconto\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
class Employee extends AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('banktest', 'id_desconto');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you made models to save data? Also, did you reach the save controller on Save button click?

Comment: yes, i go a post

Comment: You only need "Save" controller code?

Comment: I posted as models. I think so, because I already have the models, the Ui components, and the Blocks. However I don't know which code I put in the controller to save it to save it in the database.

Comment: If you can verify that the content I posted is correct, I will be grateful.

Comment: Actually there are few more files to look into but I'll suggest you to go through [link](https://webkul.com/blog/create-grid-edit-add-grid-row-and-installer-in-magento2/) to clear your concepts about this.

Comment: the link does not exist